# In magento2, How to get applicable catalog rule details for particular product

Tags: magento, magento2

I want to get all applicable catalog product rules for particular product. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I know this probably isn't the best answer as to people not wanting you to use the objectmanager, but here is a dirty way:

```
<?php 
//Get Object Manager Instance
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

//Load product by product id
$rules = $objectManager->create('Magento\CatalogRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule')->getRulesFromProduct($date, $websiteId, $customerGroupId, $productId);
```

You will need to get the variables from where ever your code is ( template file, or class etc )